# Convert OOM Items.Restrict to Redemption Items.Restrict

Tags: powershell, outlook, filtering, outlook-redemption

I'm trying to convert the following working powershell OOM items.restrict:

```
$colMail = $olFolder.Items.Restrict("[Start] > '18/03/2022'")
$colMail = $olFolder.Items.Restrict("[Subject] = 'Test'")
```

RDO items.restrict

```
$SQL = "Subject = 'Test'" # or "where Subject = 'Test'"
$colMail = $olFolder.Items.Restrict($SQL)
$colMail = $olFolder.Items.Restrict("Subject = 'Test'")
$colMail = $olFolder.Items.Restrict("where Subject = 'Test'")
$colMail = $olFolder.Items.Restrict("Start > '2022-03-18'")
```

Neither of the RDO examples does return any items.
Also items.find isnt't working with RDO.

What is the correct SQL-statement in Powershell?

Thanks

Comment: All 4 queries should work fine. Are you sure you retrieve the right folder?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the [documentation](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo/RDOItems.htm#methods) says:

> SQL style query specifying the condition. Can either be a WHERE part only (e.g. "LastName = 'Streblechenko' ") or a complete SQL expression with the SELECT, WHERE and ORDER BY clauses (see example).

> The properties specified in the SQL query must either use the Outlook Object Model (or RDO) property name (e.g. Subject, Email1Address) or a DASL style property name (e.g. "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001E", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8083001E")

> When a DASL property name is used, it must be enclosed in double quotes.

> Including the SELECT clause allows Redemption to pre-fetch the properties from the folder contents table without opening the item resulting in a significant performance gain (see example). If you later access a property not specified in the SELECT clause, Redemption will open the item.

> Including the ORDER BY clause sorts the collection in the specified order.

For example:

```
set Contact = Items.Restrict("SELECT Email1Address, FileAs from Folder WHERE LastName = 'PersonLastName' ORDER BY FirstName desc")
```